# How do you add to a new index on a Multi-dimensional array within a foreach loop?

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array, foreach

Hell once again, I am wondering how do you go about adding data to a new array index when inside a foreach loop?

the code I have atm is,

```
// Connect to the database to gather all data pertaiing to the link in question
$assoResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM associate_users");
while ($assoRow = mysql_fetch_field($assoResult)) {
    $resultArray[] = $assoRow->name;
}

// Connect to the database to gather all data pertaiing to the link in question
$assoResult2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM associate_users WHERE id='$getID'");
while ($assoRow2 = mysql_fetch_object($assoResult2)) {

    foreach ($resultArray as $row) { 
        $array = array(array( 1 => $assoRow2->$row, 2 => $row, ),);
        echo "<br />"; print_r($array);
    }               
}
```

Below is the outputted data that comes from the "echo "br />"; print_r($array);" line.

=================================================================

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => id ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Bob[2] => contactName ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Bob's Tyres [2] => company ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX [2] => address1 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX [2] => address2 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXXXXX [2] => address3 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXX [2] => postcode ) )
```

As you can see the array is being created a new over and over, what I need is for the above data to increment the 1st dimension index key on every loop, so it looks like...

=================================================================

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => id ) )
Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => Bob[2] => contactName ) )
Array ( [2] => Array ( [1] => Bob's Tyres [2] => company ) )
Array ( [3] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX [2] => address1 ) )
Array ( [4] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX [2] => address2 ) )
Array ( [5] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXXXXX [2] => address3 ) )
Array ( [6] => Array ( [1] => XXXXXX [2] => postcode ) )
```

Thank you in advance I am out of all options in getting this to work and desperate.

Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the values assigning part of your code to

```
    $count=0; 
    foreach ($resultArray as $row) { 
            $array[$count][1] = $assoRow2->$row
            $array[$count][2]=$row;
            $count++;
            echo "<br />"; print_r($array);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code gets you the output you asked for without inefficiently using two queries:

```
// Connect to the database to gather all data pertaining to the link in question
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM associate_users WHERE id=" . (int)$getID);

$resultArray = array();
$resultCount = 0;
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$count = 0;
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[$count] = array(1 => $value, 2 => $key);
    $count++;

    echo "<br />"; print_r($temp);
}
```

Why you want it like this, I have no idea.

Comment: I am not sure if you have noticed my use of "mysql_fetch_field" in the first sql query? I am using 2 due to using the field fetch in one query and a standard object fetch in the other, if they can both be combined into 1 query I would love to know how (unless you have shown that above and I simply cannot see that)?

Comment: Unless you have some other code which is doing something else we can't see, there should be no need to use that first query and `mysql_fetch_field` to fetch all the field names. My code here should result in identical output to the desired output you posted in your question. The code in your question will fetch every link from the `associate_users` table, just for the purpose of then fetching a single link. If your `associate_users` table gets large, this could slow down your page. If you *know* your table will stay small, just stick with what you have if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //extra code.declaring array
$array = array();
while ($assoRow2 = mysql_fetch_object($assoResult2)) {
    foreach ($resultArray as $row) { 
// 1st parameter is the array name, here array name is array .give gd name according to use
       array_push($array,array( 1 => $assoRow2->$row, 2 => $row, ));
        echo "<br />"; print_r($array);
    }               
}
```